# Is JBoss 7.1( latest Jboss) compatible with Java 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

Need to develop services to deploy on latest version of JBoss, not sure if I can use Java 7 . Initially decided to compile to Java 6. But really would like to use Java 7, can I do this. Will Jboss support features of Java 7 ?
Roman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight from the [Getting Started guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-Requirements):

> ## Requirements
>
> Java SE 6 or later (we recommend that you use the latest update available)
>
> Java SE 7 can be used with JBoss AS 7