# Compatibility of Java 1.7 with infinispan in clustered mode

Tags: hibernate, jboss, infinispan

I'm planning to use infinispan for distributed caching. I just needed to know a few things before i could start up with configuring it in jboss. Is infinispan 5.1.5(Brahma) and jboss 7.1 compatible with  java 1.7 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7.1 and Java 1.7 compatibility is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977341/is-jboss-7-1-latest-jboss-compatible-with-java-7). WRT Infinispan, I'd suggest you use version 5.3.0.CR1. We test it with Java 7 and works fine too. Finally, if you wanna use that Infinispan version, which is different to the one shipped in AS7, you'll have to ship it in your deployment to get isolation.

Comment: Thanks Zamarreno. Which version of infinispan is shipped currently with AS7? I didn't quite understand. I'm also using hibernate 3.5. Later if i want to upgrade to hibernate 4 will that cause issues?

Comment: From what you can see in https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/7.1/pom.xml#L145, the latest AS7 branch ships 5.1.8. Latest release might have an earlier 5.1.x version. Not sure what exactly you're gonna do with Infinispan, but if your use case is as Hibernate 2LC, use whatever Infinispan version comes with that Hibernate version. Easier is always going to be to stick to libraries provided by the app server though...